# Can you use Pinia in Composition API's <script setup> tags?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-composition-api, pinia, vue-options-api

**Background**

I'm creating an App in Vue3 using Composition API. I decided to use `<script setup>` tags for all my components and views because I wanted to use the most up to date syntax for my app in Vue3's Composition API.

**Confusion**

However, when looking through the [docs](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/options-api.html), I noticed that Pinia is designed to be used inside setup() inside of `<script>` tags? I thought the setup() function was a way to enable Composition API features inside an older Options API app?

I naturally assumed that Pinia would be designed to work natively within `<script setup>` as it is recommended as the state management tool for all new Vue3 projects. In the main Vue.js [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles), they use `<script setup>` for their sample of Composition API.

**Question**

So I guess I have two parts to the questions:

1. Why would they design Pinia to integrate only with Options API `<script>` instead of Composition API `<script setup>`?
2. How do you use Pinia with `<script setup>` and is there documentation for this?

*I could also be ignorant to something, but if anyone could offer some clarity to this I'd be grateful so I would not have to refactor all my components to Options API with a setup() function.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script setup>` is only a syntax sugar for Composition API with `setup()`. Anything that you can do with `setup()` can be done with `<script setup>`. `<script setup>` helps you write code almost like standard JavaScript, instead of having to follow the Vue-specific syntax.

I'm not sure why you thought Pinia can only be integrated with Options API. In `<script setup>` you can use Pinia like the following:

Your `component.vue` file:

```js
<script
  setup
  lang="ts">
  import {useStore} from './store'
  const store = useStore()
</script>
<template>
  <p>{{store.text}}</p>
</template>
```

Your `store.ts` file:

```
import {defineStore} from 'pinia'
export const useStore = defineStore('main', {
  state: () => (<{
    text : string
  }>{
    text: 'This is some text'
  })
})
```

Comment: I am looking at the docs and most of the main examples exist within setup() functions. I need to keep reading a bit more, thanks for the example though, makes sense!